# Are these files part of owasp zap 2.6: nc.exe, cmd.war, cmd.aspx

Tags: updates, owasp, antivirus, zap

I was updating my OWASP ZAP 2.6 and my webroot detected these files simultaneously: `cmd.war`, `nc.exe`, and `cmd.aspx` as threats.

Are these used by zap or are they an actual threat to my system? Currently they are in quarantine. I need to know before I erase them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are part of the FuzzDb add-on. We dont include this in ZAP by default because antivirus sw often flags them.

FYI they are in source control here:

- https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/master/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/fuzzdb/files/fuzzers/fuzzdb/web-backdoors/jsp/laudanum
- https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/master/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/fuzzdb/files/fuzzers/fuzzdb/web-backdoors/exe
- https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/tree/master/src/org/zaproxy/zap/extension/fuzzdb/files/fuzzers/fuzzdb/web-backdoors/asp

Obviously we dont beleive they are a threat or we wouldnt have included them, but you can safely delete them - ZAP doennt rely on them.